# Is the german "Warsteiner" a Pilsner?

Tags: brewing, breweries, german-beers

I've heard lately, that the german beer [*Warsteiner*](http://www.warsteiner.com/) <strike>does not fullfill the german [**Reinheitsgebot**](https://alcohol.stackexchange.com/a/431/4947) and therefore is</strike> is not allowed to be called [*Pilsner*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pilsner), that is why they call it a *Premium Verum*.

Is that true and if yes, why?

Comment: Where did you get that information? On their website (http://www.warsteiner.de/reinheitsgebot/), it says: „Die Warsteiner Brauerei legt seit ihrem Bestehen, mittlerweile also über 260 Jahre, größten Wert auf die Einhaltung des deutschen Reinheitsgebots, dessen Ursprungsversion als bayrisches Reinheitsgebot seit 1516 Bestand hat.“ Short version: They have always been adhering to the reinheitsgebot.

Comment: @Philipp I was wondering why it is called "Premium Verum" and a friend told me, that they are not allowed to call it a *Pilsner* and therefore called it a "Premium Verum"

Comment: I’m not sure about what has to be fulfilled to be allowed to call a beer a pilsner.

Comment: They called it "Premium Pilsner" earlier.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think your friend got the wrong end of a stick :p

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Warsteiner#Warsteiner_Premium_Verum) lists it as a pilsner, so does [BeerAdvocate](http://www.beeradvocate.com/beer/profile/360/935/) and the [Warsteiner](http://www.warsteiner.com/our-beer/premium-verum/) site.

I think Premium Verum is just a name.

Answer (score 2):

"premium verum" is just a marketing-joke. Warsteiner is a real "Pilsener".
And they brew according to the german purity law.

Martin (I studied Brewing Science in Weihenstephan and know Warsteiner very well)

Answer (score -2):

As far as I read, Warsteiner is not a Pilsener because they don't use enough hops. It's like a Pilsener but less bitter.

Comment: If the beer is fresh it is bitter and refreshing. Considering that it is a classic example of style (BJCP 2008) I doubt that they use less hops. http://www.bjcp.org/2008styles/style02.php#1a